Fiat 500 becomes impossible to shift into first/reverse gear after driving slow in traffic jams
Car is a FIAT 500, Year of manufacture 2013, 1242cc petrol.
Earlier this year there began to be issues shifting into reverse gear, infrequently. Then the garage spotted there was a leak of gearbox oil, and they suggested fitting a reconditioned gearbox.
After this, the gear lever felt much less smooth. The light on the dashboard ceased to light up to suggest moving into fifth gear. Reverse started to crunch as you shifted.
After a month, whenever there was bad traffic queues, and there was a lot of stop/start, and the gear lever refused to move into first. Pumping the clutch doesn't solve it. Turning engine off, wiggling the lever, waiting a minute, usually got it going again.
But it has started to happen every week now. Shifting out of first into second is now very difficult too.
Clutch fluid level is fine. Garage have looked at car twice (cold engine) and declared nothing is wrong. One it gets hot in a traffic jam (or you are using the clutch a lot) it will refuse to shift again, and requires a wait on the hard shoulder for a few minutes.
What would cause the lever to refuse to engage, despite mechanics assuring us it is fine?
Could it be a problem with the gear lever, or the wires connecting to the engine, rather than the gearbox itself?
